# SQL count number of patients who have issue of same drug 3 or more times?

Tags: sql, count

I would be *really* grateful for some help…

I had a table with patients in it, PAT.ID, an EVENT.CD, and EVENT.DT (date)
I am interested for the EVENT.YR = 2019, to COUNT how many times any unique PAT.ID had 3 or more occurrences of a specific drug EVENT.CD = d4% in that year.

I can produce a table showing rows with a separate entry each time a Patient got the drug (so if the patient got the drug 6 times in 2019, the patient.iD will have six row entries showing each EVENT.DT), but I cannot work out how to get a count of only those unique patients who had multiple issues of the drug (set as 3 or more times) in 2019. (So if => 3 events for a patient, they would get counted only once).

Been battling this for 2 days as a novice and getting nowhere . Please show mercy

Comment: Post a sample of data and expected output, it would make things easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's more to the problem than this, so here's some sample data along with the SQL. There's no specific DB tag, so this is straight ANSI SQL:

```
create table T1(PAT_ID int, EVENT_CD varchar(10), EVENT_DT date);

insert into T1 (PAT_ID, EVENT_CD, EVENT_DT) values
(1, 'd4r', '2019-01-01'),
(2, 'abc', '2019-01-01'),
(3, 'def', '2019-01-01'),
(1, 'd4r', '2019-04-15'),
(1, 'd4e', '2019-09-05'),
(1, 'd4s', '2020-06-12'),
(1, 'def', '2019-01-01'),
(3, 'd4s', '2019-08-17'),
(3, 'd4s', '2019-12-10'),
(2, 'd4s', '2019-11-17');

select PAT_ID, count(*) as EVENT_COUNT
from T1
where   EVENT_DT >= '2019-01-01'
    and EVENT_DT <= '2019-12-31'
group by PAT_ID, left(EVENT_CD,2)
having count(*) >= 3
;
```

| PAT_ID | EVENT_COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |

[SQL Server 2019 Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5fc928cbaa4228fff73d37af7abfbc59)

Comment: Thanks for this, I think it’s getting there. However, I wasn’t clear, the code d4% is for a class of drugs, not one specific one. - so one might be d4r, one might be d4s, hence the use of rhe % as a wild card. 

If I run your excellent script it’s certainly nearly doing it, but if I run with event-CD = d4%, then it returns nothing,

Comment: I have updated the answer, sample data, and fiddle. All you need to change is the `group by` expression. Just make sure it matches what you want to group. In this case it's using `left()` to group on the first two characters. You can group by most string functions including if you need them, regular expressions.